# Can I use try catch exceptions into PDO transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my script:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();                               // this

    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET col = "updated" WHERE id = ?");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));
    $done = $stm->rowCount();

    if ($done){
        try {
            $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (col) VALUES (?)");
            $stm2->execute(array($id));

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {  // row is duplicate
                $stm3 = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table2 WHERE col = ?");
                $stm3->execute(array($id));
            }
        }

    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    $db_conn->commit();                                          // this
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

First of all, I have to say, my script works. I mean the result or it is as expected in tests. Just one thing scares me. I read the documention and seen this sentence:

> Won't work and is dangerous since you could close your transaction too early with the nested commit().

I'm not sure what's the meaning of sentence above, just I understand maybe I shouldn't use nested `try - catch` between `beginTransaction()` and `commit()`. Well I got it right? doing that is dangerous?

Comment: Where is that in the documentation?

Comment: if you are using transaction, you don't have to delete the record on error, just do a rollback... And the sentence is about nested `beginTransaction()`/`commit()`, not about try/catch...

Comment: @Phil http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php

Comment: You're using prepared statements, which is great, but try and make a habit of putting all data values in as binds, including things like `"updated"`.

Comment: @tadman Do you mean I shouldn't use prepared statements for `UPDATE` statement ?

Comment: @n00dl3 I edited my scrip, So I using rollback cannot be an alternative for that `DELETE` statement. Am I right?

Comment: You absolutely should use prepared statements whenever possible. I mean specifically the string `"updated"` in your example should be bound as well. `SET col=? WHERE id=?`.

Comment: Anything inserted, updated, or deleted during a transaction will get rolled back if you do not commit the transaction. Don't try and unwind it manually with a `DELETE`. Abandon the transaction instead by by rolling it back. In other words, have a single exception handler at the end only. You already have one there, but the inner rescue is a problem.

Comment: @tadman Ah I see. But I think I didn't say what I'm trying to do exactly. I cannot use `rollBack()` instead of that `DELETE` statement. Because I'm trying to insert a row, and I want to remove it if it is duplicate ..! If I rollback, then still that row will be exists. *(while I want to remove it)*

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this. If you have a collision on `INSERT` you want to delete the row? You could try `INSERT IGNORE` and the find out if it was successfully inserted, and if not, then pull the existing row with a secondary `DELETE`. This avoids having to trap exceptions. Why I find this odd is running this code once would insert a row, twice would remove it, and three times would insert it again.

Comment: @tadman I don't want *"once would insert a row, twice would remove it"*, There is two cases: 1. The row exists already. 2. The row isn't exist already. I want to insert that row, and if it already exists, then I want to remove it.

Comment: @stack You're describing exactly what I'm saying. Inserting would create it. The second call would find the previously created record and remove it. The third call would find no record and insert one. It would flip-flop back and forth forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions have no direct relation to transactions. You can add as many catch blocks in your code as you need.

So your code is all right, given you already set PDO error reporting to Exceptions.

Comment: Your answer is 1 line and exactly what I needed to hear ..! I don't know why nobody else didn't say that so far. thank you .. upvote

Comment: Just one thing, I don't know English very well. May you please rephrase this sentence for me? *"given you already set PDO error reporting to Exceptions."*

Comment: Your code is OK if you already set PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE to PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

Comment: Do you mean this one after connecting? `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Anyway you are a good person for answering to obsessed people. Because your answers are `0` or `1`. I mean you literally say your code is *true* or *false* without any redundant explanation.

Comment: May you please tell me [how many `rollBack()` my script needs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640107/how-many-rollback-should-i-write-in-a-transaction)? I'm pinging you because mentioned question is containing pretty similar codes.

Comment: @stack, i am out of reach from a desktop pc for a week so i cant write  full featured answer. But you need to get rid of all conditions and undos in your code, leaving it straight two statements (update and insert)within one try catch block with single rollback