# How many rollback should I write in a transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Hare is my script:

```
$id    = $_GET['id'];
$value = $_GET['val'];

// database connection here

try{
    $db_conn->beginTransaction();

    $stm1 = $db_conn->prepare("UPDATE table1 SET col = 'updated' WHERE id = ?");
    $stm1->execute(array($value));
    $done = $stm->rowCount();

    if ($done){
        try {
            $stm2 = $db_conn->prepare("INSERT into table2 (col) VALUES (?)");
            $stm2->execute(array($id));

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            if ((int) $e->getCode() === 23000) {  // row is duplicate
                $stm3 = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM table2 WHERE col = ?");
                $stm3->execute(array($id));

            } else {
                $db_conn->rollBack();    // is this line of code necessarily ??
            }
        }

    } else {
        $error = true;
    }

    $db_conn->commit(); 
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    $db_conn->rollBack();
}
```

As you see, there is multiple (nested) `try - catch` blocks in my script. So I want to know, does any `catch` block need its own `rollBack()` or should I just write it once for the whole of script?

---

**EDIT:** Also as a note, that `DELETE` statement acts as an *undo*. Suppose you give a vote to a post and you want to take it back. So that `DELETE` statement remove it if you send a vote twice.

Comment: There is a PHP syntax error on your first `UPDATE`. You need to fix the nested double quotes.

Comment: It's not very clear what your objective is. Whether each catch has it's own rollback depends really on what changes you want committed and what you don't want to be committed. And this question really doesn't have that information

Comment: Then why just delete from table2 and leave table1 changes intact?

Comment: @e4c5 Actually voting-system was just an example. In reality *table1* is nothing to do with *table2*..! I want to update *table1* then insert/delete something of *table2*.

Comment: well your information is still sketchy to say the least but it sounds like your current rollback setup is ok

Comment: @e4c5 Ah ok, thx for your attention.